# Store preferred user name?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am doing a college assessment at the moment but no further along solving it and needing advice or guidance.

I'll give you the question example..

1. Declare and set score variable to 0
2. prompt user to input user name

   a. Store preferred user name

Now when it says "**Store preferred user name** " is this to do with arrays and loops? I was off class that day ill and I'm struggling.

any suggestions would be great thanks

Comment: from this information alone it's hard to tell what is meant by "store". I'm guessing all they want you to do is save (assign) a variable the value returned by calling `prompt()`. I don't see the need for loops or arrays. However, it's probably best to email your tutor/professor when seeking clarity about assessments

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that they are looking for something like this.

```js
let score = 0;
let userName = prompt('What is your username?')
```